# select control in wpfgrid

Tags: wpf, qtp

Please let me know if you have already worked in wpf based windows application

my query is How to retrieve objects from a WPFGrid control in qtp. when spying, qtp is identifing only the WPFGrid and note the objects inside it. pls suggest workaround for this

WpfWindow("title").WpfTable("title")

Inside the wpftable there are four columns and some rows. first column contains chechboxes. i want to check/uncheck that. anything inside the wpftable are not recognized by object spy

Regards

Answer (score 1):

You want to perform an operation on CheckBoxes , if yes, than you need to

WpfWindow("title").WpfTable("title").WpfCheckBox("index:=0").Click

Spy the check box and check for the property.

Comment: HI Thanks for the comments but the problem is that the checkboxes are not getting recognized in the qtp. i am getting hierachy as WpfWindow("title").WpfTab("title").

Comment: qtp is not specifing any object in the wpftable separately, on spying any object in the wpftable, only wpftable is returned and not any object inside it. error displayed on running above code is Cannot find the "[ WpfCheckBox ]" object's parent "Real-time View" (class WpfWindow). Verify that parent properties match an object currently displayed in your application.

Comment: pls reply to above query related to wpftable